# return member IDs who only used the business for 1 service out of many and may have used the business multiple times

Tags: sql-server

I need to return the member IDs that have used only service 'a' when a few different services are available.

Eg. from the table the query would return member 1 and member 5 as they have only ever used service a.

```
memberID    service date
1              a    1
1              a    2
2              a    3
2              b    4
3              c    5
1              a    6
3              c    7
4              a    8
4              c    9
5              a    10
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Probably more elegant ways of doing this but I think it will work

```
WITH DC AS
(
SELECT
    memberID
FROM
    [Table]
GROUP BY
    memberID
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT [service]) = 1
    )
SELECT DISTINCT
    DC.*
FROM
    DC
CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT [Table].memberID FROM [Table] AS S WHERE S.memberID = DC.memberID AND S.[service] = 'a'
    )
    AS X
```